# Looping datareader using For Next VB.NET :There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: for-loop, vb.net-2010, unhandled-exception, mysqldatareader

```vb
For x=0 To 2
    Dim FO As String
    Dim DataQuery1 As String
    DataQuery1 = "Select * from dole_employees WHERE fullname like '%" & Temp_Employees_Name & "%'"
    mysqlcommand = New MySqlCommand(DataQuery1, mconnection)
    readme = mysqlcommand.ExecuteReader()
    While readme.Read()
        FO = readme(1)
    End While
    readme.Close()
    MsgBox(FO)
Next
```

After it displays the value in `FO` once, an unhandled exception error occurs. What should I do with that?

Here is the additional information to unhandled exemption error.
Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
But there is already a readme.close() so why does this happen?

Comment: What exception is it?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

This one..when I try to remove the loop, it works fine..but I want to this block of codes depending on a quantity to be entered by a user.

Comment: @JannVincent edit your question to add that exception.

Comment: I already added the additional information to the question. How can I fix this problem? pls.